# Compile-Time Calculation Of Nested Descendants

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, template-meta-programming, compile-time

Given the following base template struct:

```cpp
template <typename ElementType, int ElementSize>
struct Base
{
    // ...
}
```

and some descendants of the following form:

```cpp
template <typename ElementType, TCount ElementSize>
struct Descendant1 : public Base<ElementType, ElementSize>
{
    // ...
}
```

the desire is to write a template function that will take a parameter whose type is a tree of template Base descendants down to a non-template-Base element, and return a "flattened" Base-descendant of all of the elements from the tree parameter.  For example:

```cpp
template <typename ElementType, int ElementSize>
auto Flatten(const Base<ElementType, ElementSize>& tree)
{
    static constexpr auto resultSize{CompileTimeNumberOfTreeElements<ElementType, ElementSize>};
    auto result{Descendant1<ElementType, resultSize>{}};
    // code that fills "result"
    return result;
}
```

An example invocation of Flatten might be:

```cpp
using Component = Descendant1<int, 3>;
using Composition = Descendant2(Component, 7);

auto answer{Flatten(Composition{Component{1, 4}, Component{1, 2, 3}, Component{7, 10}})};
```

The answer will contain a descendant of Base with the elements [1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 10].

Note that Composition and Component can be sparse.

I **CANNOT** figure out how to write **CompileTimeNumberOfTreeElements**!

I have spent many hours researching Template Meta Programming, and have been unable to design a solution.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems you mix `<>`, `()` and `{}`.

Comment: As Base has only one type, I don't see the tree... would be possible with pair or tuple...

Comment: Does [how-to-flatten-heterogeneous-lists-aka-tuples-of-tuples-of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931352/how-to-flatten-heterogeneous-lists-aka-tuples-of-tuples-of) answer to your question?